# Execute multiline mysql in shellscript

Tags: mysql, bash

When I attempt to execute a multi-line SQL in mysql via shell script:

```
mysql -uroot -ppass mydb <<<EOF
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'table.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM mytable limit 1;
EOF
```

I get a syntax error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EOF' at line 1
```

What's the right way to script it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The syntax for [bash heredoc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) is:

```
COMMAND <<InputComesFromHERE
...
...
...
InputComesFromHERE
```

So you have an extra `<`.

In order to prepare and test you can replace `COMMAND` (i.e. `mysql -uroot -ppass mydb` in this case) with `cat` to have a look at the exact SQL code that will be executed.

Answer (score 4):

For future readers, one easy way is as follows if they wish to export in bulk using bash, tested on mariadb, same should work in mysql too.

```
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ mysql -u someuser -p test -e "select * from offices"
Enter password: 
+------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| officeCode | city          | phone            | addressLine1             | addressLine2 | state      | country   | postalCode | territory |
+------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| 1          | San Francisco | +1 650 219 4782  | 100 Market Street        | Suite 300    | CA         | USA       | 94080      | NA        |
| 2          | Boston        | +1 215 837 0825  | 1550 Court Place         | Suite 102    | MA         | USA       | 02107      | NA        |
| 3          | NYC           | +1 212 555 3000  | 523 East 53rd Street     | apt. 5A      | NY         | USA       | 10022      | NA        |
| 4          | Paris         | +33 14 723 4404  | 43 Rue Jouffroy D'abbans | NULL         | NULL       | France    | 75017      | EMEA      |
| 5          | Tokyo         | +81 33 224 5000  | 4-1 Kioicho              | NULL         | Chiyoda-Ku | Japan     | 102-8578   | Japan     |
| 6          | Sydney        | +61 2 9264 2451  | 5-11 Wentworth Avenue    | Floor #2     | NULL       | Australia | NSW 2010   | APAC      |
| 7          | London        | +44 20 7877 2041 | 25 Old Broad Street      | Level 7      | NULL       | UK        | EC2N 1HN   | EMEA      |
+------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------------+--------------+------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

**If you're exporting by non-root user then set permission like below**

```
root@ideapad:/tmp# mysql -u root -p
MariaDB[(none)]> UPDATE mysql.user SET File_priv = 'Y' WHERE user='someuser' AND host='localhost';
```

**Restart or Reload mysqld**

```
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ sudo su
root@ideapad:/tmp#  systemctl restart mariadb
```

**Sample code snippet**

```
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ cat test.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

user="someuser"
password="password"
database="test"

mysql -u"$user" -p"$password" "$database" <<EOF
SELECT * 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/csvs/offices.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM offices;
EOF
```

**Execute**

```
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ mkdir -p /tmp/csvs
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ chmod +x test.sh
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ ./test.sh 
akshay@ideapad:/tmp$ cat /tmp/csvs/offices.csv 
"1"|"San Francisco"|"+1 650 219 4782"|"100 Market Street"|"Suite 300"|"CA"|"USA"|"94080"|"NA"
"2"|"Boston"|"+1 215 837 0825"|"1550 Court Place"|"Suite 102"|"MA"|"USA"|"02107"|"NA"
"3"|"NYC"|"+1 212 555 3000"|"523 East 53rd Street"|"apt. 5A"|"NY"|"USA"|"10022"|"NA"
"4"|"Paris"|"+33 14 723 4404"|"43 Rue Jouffroy D'abbans"|\N|\N|"France"|"75017"|"EMEA"
"5"|"Tokyo"|"+81 33 224 5000"|"4-1 Kioicho"|\N|"Chiyoda-Ku"|"Japan"|"102-8578"|"Japan"
"6"|"Sydney"|"+61 2 9264 2451"|"5-11 Wentworth Avenue"|"Floor #2"|\N|"Australia"|"NSW 2010"|"APAC"
"7"|"London"|"+44 20 7877 2041"|"25 Old Broad Street"|"Level 7"|\N|"UK"|"EC2N 1HN"|"EMEA"
```